# ionic5 android when keyboard show it covers input and content not scroll

Tags: android, ionic-framework

my project info is

```
  "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
  "cordova-android": "^6.4.0",
  "@ionic/angular": "^5.2.2",
  "@ionic-native/keyboard": "^5.26.0",
```

and my login html is

```
 <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label position="fixed">
        <ion-icon slot="start" color="primary" name="person"></ion-icon>
        账号
      </ion-label>
      <ion-input placeholder="请输入账号" [(ngModel)]="user.name"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label position="fixed">
        <ion-icon slot="start" color="primary" name="lock-closed"></ion-icon>
        密码
      </ion-label>
      <ion-input type="password" placeholder="请输入密码" [(ngModel)]="user.pwd"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

ionic5 android hide input when keyboard show, and  content not auto scroll

how can i solve this? many thanks